# What made Born interpret $|\psi|^2$ as a probability density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, history, born-rule

What was Born reasoning when he introduced the rule that $|\psi|^2$ could be interpreted as a probability density?

Comment: Would this be better on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score -1):

You can consider the position basis, made of delta functions $\delta(x_i) \, \forall x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ (in $1$D).

You can write your wavefunction $\psi(x)$ in terms of that basis: $$ \psi(x) = \sum_i a_i \delta(x-i) = \int \mathrm{d}x_i\, a(x_i)\,\delta(x-x_i),$$
where $a_i$ is the probability amplitude of being at a specific position $x=i$.

If you try and reverse the relation to isolate $a_i$:
$$ a(x) = \int \psi(y)\delta(x-y)\, \mathrm{d}y = \psi(x).$$

So the probability amplitude $a(x)$ in the position basis *is equal* to your original wavefunction $\psi(x)$.